# Issue moving Ubuntu/Apache webserver from Comcast to AT&T router

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, router, port-forwarding, syn

I've hosted a simple Ubuntu web server for years on port 443 via a Comcast router with port forwarding enabled without issue.

I now have to change to AT&T, the router they provided is a BGW320, which also has port forwarding that I've enabled on 443.

The web server still works perfectly when accessed externally via the Comcast router.  When switching to the BGW320, the web server is no longer accessible.

When connected to the BGW320 I can confirm with `tcpdump` that simple external port scan TCP [SYN] packets are received at the server, but a [SYN,ACK] response never happens from Apache.

Things I've tried which have not worked include:

`sudo ufw status` = `Status: inactive`

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=0 
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=0
```

`sudo ethtool --offload  eno1  rx off  tx off`

I confirmed that port forwarding is working as expected by disabling it, and verifying no packet transmission with `tcpdump`.

I can confirm the web server works fine on the internal network.

I also tried running the Rebex tiny web server on a windows box (with port forwarding changed), that works as expected without issue and is accessible externally through the BGW320.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions that would help me test or try to resolve this, thank you serverfault community!